# The notion of the "Nolting" Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, reference-request, multilinear-algebra, exterior-algebra

In the "Multilinear Algebra" by W. Greub it is mentioned that for a vector space $V$ over the field $k$, one can define the 'Nolting Algebra'. Let's name it $N_V$ for the sake of discussion. Then,

$$
   N_V = \bigoplus^\infty_{n=0} V^{\wedge 2n}
$$

is a commutative subalgebra of the exterior algebra $\bigwedge V$. moreover, it seems that $N_V$ the centre of ${\bigwedge}V$ when $\mathrm{char} \; k \neq 2$ and $\dim V$ is even.

However I failed to find any other references bysides Greub "Multilinear Algebra" for the term "Nolting Algebra". So here is my question:

> What is the convential name for the algebra of even exterior powers $N_V$?
>
> Does $N_V$ has any other applications besides being sometimes the centre of $\bigwedge V$?

Comment: $N_V$ is not the center of $\bigwedge V$ when $\dim V \leq 1$. I guess it is the center otherwise (but I don't have time to check).

Comment: I have seen this algebra being used, but I don't quite remember where :( I think it was involved in studying the Pfaffian of an alternating matrix, or proving the Amitsur-Levitzki identity, or both.

Comment: Ah, right: [Shmuel Rosset, *A new proof of the Amitsur-Levitski identity*](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02756797) is the second application I remembered.

Comment: You are right, if $\dim V = 1$, then  $\bigwedge V$ is commutative itself with $\dim V = 2$, and $N_V$ is just an isomorphic copy of $k$, where $k$ is a ground field of $V$.

Comment: Actually, perhaps $N_V + V^{\wedge \dim V}$ is the center of $\bigwedge V$. (Of course, this is the same as $N_V$ when $\dim V$ is even.)

Comment: @darijgrinberg  Thank you for the reference